# Yes/No always pick the first option (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm really new in C++. Currently helping my sister about this. I'm making a standard restaurant cashier program, with a little code to count the change money. At the end i would like to ask whether the user may continue or exit. I am using goto statement, if the user press Y it will go back, and if user press N it will exit.

My problem is the code only accept the first (go back) option. So if I press N the program won't exit. Can you please help me? Here are my code at the end:

```
cout<<"again?";
cin>>response;
if (response == 'Y') {
goto a;
}
else if (response == 'N') {
exit(0);
}
```

edit 1

```
            cout<<"\nAgain?";
        cin>>response;
        if (response == 'Y'||'y'){
            main();


        }     
        else if (response == 'N'||'n'){
            exit(0);
        }
```

edit 1
changed the code so when the user press Y it will go back to the top. how do you exit the loop if using this snippet?

```
cout<<"\nMasukan Jumlah Pembelian Untuk Menu A : "; //input for Menu A and B quantities
        cin>>jml_menu_A;
        hrg_menu1=menu_A*jml_menu_A; //calculation
        cout<<"\nTotal Harga untuk Menu A : "<<menu_A<<" * "<<jml_menu_A<<" = Rp "<<hrg_menu1<<",00\n";
        cout<<"\nMasukan Jumlah Pembelian Untuk Menu B : ";
        cin>>jml_menu_B;
        hrg_menu2=menu_B*jml_menu_B; //calculation
        cout<<"\nTotal Harga untuk Menu B : "<<menu_B<<" * "<<jml_menu_B<<" = Rp "<<hrg_menu2<<",00\n";


        ttal_bayar=ttal_hrg_menu_A+ttal_hrg_menu_B;
        cout<<"\nMaka yang Harus Dibayarkan : "<<ttal_hrg_menu_A<<"+"<<ttal_hrg_menu_B<<"= Rp "<<ttal_bayar<<",00\n"; // total payment

        //Bayar;
        cout<<"\nMasukan Uang untuk pembayaran : ";
        cin>>uang;
        kembalian=uang-ttal_bayar; //total payment

        {
        if (uang>=ttal_bayar){ // change if the money is more
                    kembalian=uang-ttal_bayar;

                    cout<<"\nKembaliannya adalah..."<<kembalian<<" Rupiah..";
        }
        else if (uang<ttal_bayar){ // if the payment is less
                    kembalian=uang-ttal_bayar;

                    cout<<"\nMaaf Kembalian Anda Kurang";
        }

        }

        cout<<"\nApakah ada transaksi lain?"; // confirm to start all over, or exit the program
        cin>>response;
        if (response == 'Y'||'y'){
            main();
        }     
        else if (response == 'N'||'n'){
            exit(0);
        }
```

}

edit 2: added the expected input and output

Comment: It's nice of you to help your sister. However considering you are this new to C++ you don't know the best practices and would probably pass bad habits to your sister. I suggest reading a book on C++ first.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I was learning C++ at college 5 years ago and now totally forgotten about it.

Comment: Don't use `goto`. Use a `while` or `do..while` loop instead, and exit the loop if the response is `N`. Also, you should be checking for `y` and `n` in addition to `Y` and `N`

Comment: A common pitfall with `char response; cin >> response` is that  the input buffer might contain a newline from a previously input (e.g.  an integral value).

Comment: ok I will try to use while loop. the full code is still a mess so might considering create a new one

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: the input and calculation part seems OK. now what im confused at is when it ask the user to go back to the data input and to exit. it only pick the first option. I am using if as mentioned above. how do exit the loop?

Comment: Show  some more  code together with input and expected output, please.

Comment: Calling `main` inside a program may be worse than using `goto`. The behaviour of `goto` is predictable if potentially tricky. Invoking `main`'s behaviour is completely undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
char foo;

while(true)
{
    cout<<"again? ";
    cin<<foo;
    if(foo == 'N' || foo =='n')
        break;
    else
    {
        //Do important stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you kind sir. Now my sister would be very happy

Answer (score 1):

```
if (response == 'Y'||'y'){
```

This statement will always be true, make it:

```
if (response == 'Y'||response == 'y'){
```

Comment: Worth a bit of expansion to explain why it is always true, 'y' != 0